# React Native: Images is not diplayed for Android devices; but shows for iOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am worked on a react native application in which we shows some static images. Images are worked perfectly worked on the initial state of app for both platforms (Android/iOS). now I don't get what's wrong, its not displayed for Android, but worked for iOS. I placed images in JS folder. I also check on perf monitor and its shows correct Image tag and width, height.

What I have tried yet :-

1. Specified Width & height.
2. Remove node_module & npm install.
3. Remove Android app & reinstall it.

PS: Same images are worked, while I have create a new Project for Android also. Its too weird.

Edit:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

class NavBarItem extends Component {
render() {
const { iconName, onPress } = this.props;
return (
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20 }}
    onPress={() => onPress()}
  >
    <Image source={require('./navigation1.png')} style = {{backgroundColor: 'green', width: 40, height: 40}} />
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
}
}

NavBarItem.propTypes = {
  iconName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onPress: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default NavBarItem;
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: @GaneshCauda I shared the code.

Comment: did you get any error ? because your code seems correct to me. maybe you can share your folder scheme, just in case you haven't found solution with this problem

Comment: or maybe you can share your project on github, so people can easily help you out

Comment: @GaneshCauda Here is the repo :- https://github.com/aadityarepos/RevenueMode.
Thanks